# How long is the gap in mp3?

Tags: audio, mp3, codec

How long is the gap in .mp3 fileformat and is it at the beginning, end or both?

I've tried to google it for an hour and still no answer.

Comment: What gap?  MP3 doesn't define any such thing...  Details would help here.